# Using javascript to calculate price in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, gridview, onblur

I'm using textbox in gridview and want to calculate values through js in textbox my code is not showing any error. I want to multiply quantity with rate and get total price.

```
function totalise(price, rate, qt) {
    var qty = window.document.getElementById(qt).value;
    var rate = window.document.getElementById(rate).value;
    var price = rate;
    price.value = rate * qty;
}

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStonePrice" runat="server" onblur=" totalise(this)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: At least you should show some of your code causing problem. There are no mind-readers here, so noone can guess what goes wrong at your side.

Comment: Please, don't post your code as comments because it is totally unreadable while being posted in that way. Use `edit` link below your question to edit it.

Comment: Please update your totalise function.  you have one function parameter in your onblur event handler but 3 parameters in function definition.  The other two are obviously not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, youre not actually passing in `rate` and `qt` to your totalise function, so you can't look them up.

Second, try using parseFloat or parseInt on those (`rate.value` and `qty`) values, otherwise they will be strings.

Third, rate already equals the value of the element with ID==rate, so after you've addressed the other 2 things I mentioned, you'll want something like this:

(note I'm ignoring some bad naming conventions.  also, you should probably do some error checking to make sure youre actually getting the elements you look up by Id)

```
function totalise(price, rate, qt) {
    var qty = window.document.getElementById(qt).value;
    var rate = window.document.getElementById(rate);
    var price = rate;
    price.value = parseFloat(rate.value) * parseFloat(qty);
}
```

Comment: his event handler is neither passing rate nor qt.  if u parseFloat(rate.value), u will get NaN.  still.. not error would show up.

Comment: @achan ahhh, wow.  I didn't realize he posted his event handler.  I've trained myself to ignore asp, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see a couple of problems here.

First, you're calling your function from `onblur` event handler as `totalise(this)`, this means you're not passing anything as `rate` and `qt` arguments, so it is impossible to get appropriate elements and retrieve their vallues.

Second, this assignment: `var price = rate;` looks redundant. You're overriding value of `price` from control you've passed to some float value, so later this call `price.value = rate * qty` will has no effect.